Why is my App Store Connect API Key not working to create a JWT in Postman?
I'm trying to make API calls to App Store Connect API and generate the JWT right in Postman.
I have the private key downloaded from my profile and the payload set as
{
    "sub": "user",
    "iat": 1722036646,
    "exp": 1722037846,
    "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1"
}

With the private key added from the downloaded file.
I'm doing GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/users and just keep getting a 401 NOT_AUTHORIZED.
Am I missing something stupid? I'm a bit rusty/out of my element but this appears to be the only way to generate a report/list of all the users I'm responsible for in the App Store.

Use https://jwt.io/ to generate bearer token. Use this:
Algorithm: ES256
Header:
{
  "alg": "ES256",
  "kid": "[your key id]",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
Payload:
{
  "iss": "[your issuer id]",
  "iat": 1734613799,
  "exp": 1734614999,
  "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1"
}

Note that 'exp' should be less than 1200 seconds from 'iat'.
Insert your private key as entire text from downloaded p8 file into 'verify signature' field.
Copy generated bearer token from the 'encoded' field.
POST https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/authorization

use your bearer token. It works for me.
